# Is writing in parallel to the values of a map thread safe?

Tags: c++, c++17

AFAIK if two unsynchronized threads access the same memory location and at least one tries to write to it, you get a data race.

This being said, in the following code sample, what is "the same memory location":

```
  std::unordered_map<int, std::string> map{{0, {}}, {1, {}}, {2, {}}, {3, {}},
                                            {4, {}}, {5, {}}, {6, {}}, {7, {}}};

  std::for_each(std::execution::par, map.begin(), map.end(),
                [](auto &kvp) { kvp.second = std::to_string(kvp.first); });
```

Is it the `map`, meaning that parallel execution introduces a data race, or, as I suspect, is it each value in `kvp`, meaning that the code is thread safe?

Comment: looks okay to me. The map is read-only. Only the strings inside are edited and each string is edited by one thread.

Comment: In this case `std::for_each` doesn't do anything which can lead to race condition. As long as your lambda passed to `std::for_each` doesn't do something strange with side effects (like accessing other elements of this map) it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most concurrent, non-`const` accesses to standard library objects do constitute data races. However, accesses through iterators are [given an explicit carveout](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/library#res.on.data.races-6.sentence-1):

> Operations on iterators obtained by calling a standard library container or string member function may access the underlying container, but shall not modify it.

Since they are non-modifying accesses to the object, they don't by themselves cause a data race.

Since no other parallel operations in your code are performing write accesses to the container object itself (just the contents of it), there are no data races inherent to your code. What you do inside the function could induce data races, but that would be through manipulation of the objects in the container, not the nature of the container itself.